# PHP Upload file to an Amazon S3 bucket via pre-signed url

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload a file to an Amazon S3 bucket via a presigned URL, that I've got from a third service. Meaning, I'm not generating this URL. I've been through  AWS documentation, but I can't put it all together. Here is what I'm referring to.

- [presignedURL.php](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/php-s3-PresignedURL.php.html)
- [Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL with AWS SDK for PHP Version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html)
- [Uploading objects using presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Currently, my code looks like this. Please note, `$key` is the presigned URL.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\CachingStream;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false ]);
$response = $client->get($image_url);
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
  'version'   => 'latest',
  'region'    => 'eu-west-1',
  'signature_version' => 'v4'
  )        
]);

$s3->putObject([
  'Bucket'        => '<BUCKET NAME HERE>',
  'Key'           => $key,
  'ContentLength' => get_headers($image_url,1)['Content-Length'],
  'ContentType'   => 'image/png',
  'Body'          => $response->getBody(),
  'ACL'           => 'private-write',
]);
```

Currently, I'm getting this error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Aws\Exception\CredentialsException: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service. (cURL error 7:  (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/) in <PATH TO SITE>\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider.php:242`

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have not passed credentials i.e. AccessKey and Secret Key while initializing S3 client.

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
  'version'   => 'latest',
  'region'    => 'eu-west-1',
  'signature_version' => 'v4',
  'credentials' => [
            'key'    => 'access-key',
            'secret' => 'secret-key' ,
        ]
  )        
]);
```

If you want to pass AccessKey and SecretKey from a file as opposed to hardcoded strings,  you can check the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443390/how-to-set-up-aws-s3-credentials-for-php#49443517) here.

Comment: I don't have the access to secret key, I don't even know it, but I do have a presigned URL which looks like this `raw/764ae0a75654fe9cb468c2b35142499b.png`. The third party software that provided me with presigned URL won't give me a secret key for obvious reasons.

Comment: If you have the presigned URL, all you need to do is make an HTTP request with PUT method to upload the object.

Comment: presigned URL is more of a URI, meaning I can't post to that, I do, however, have a URL to s3 bucket from a third party software. Do I put to that URL and pass a presigned URL as a `key`?

Comment: I think the URL from the third party software you are referring to is the presigned URL, if it's provided to you to upload objects, so I think what you are saying seems the way to go.